# Not able to get count of documents from cosmos using powershell rest API

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to query Cosmos using powershell using Rest API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents I get the below error

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request

```
Function Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$verb,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceLink,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$dateTime,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$keyType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$tokenVersion
    )
    $hmacSha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacSha256.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)

    If ($resourceLink -eq $resourceType) {
        $resourceLink = ""
    }

    $payLoad = "$($verb.ToLowerInvariant())`n$($resourceType.ToLowerInvariant())`n$resourceLink`n$($dateTime.ToLowerInvariant())`n`n"
    $hashPayLoad = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payLoad))
    $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayLoad)

[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$keyType&ver=$tokenVersion&sig=$signature")
}

Function Query-CosmosDocuments{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$EndPoint,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$DBName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$CollectionName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$MasterKey,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$JSON,      
        [String]$Verb="POST"
    )
    $ResourceType = "docs";
    $ResourceLink = "dbs/$DBName/colls/$CollectionName"
$query=@"
{  
  "query": "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c",  
  "parameters": [  ]  
} 
"@

#$query= "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c"

    $dateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")
    $authHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $Verb -resourceLink $ResourceLink -resourceType $ResourceType -key $MasterKey -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $dateTime
    $header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-documentdb-isquery"="True";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime}
    $contentType= "application/query+json"
    $queryUri = "$EndPoint$ResourceLink/docs"
    #$header
    #$queryUri

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType -Uri $queryUri -Headers $header -Body $query 
    return $result
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$CosmosDBEndPoint = "https://Mydev.documents.azure.com:443/"
$DBName = "MyDev"
$CollectionName = "ArchiveSummary"
$MasterKey = "MyMasterKey"

Query-CosmosDocuments -EndPoint $CosmosDBEndPoint -DBName $DBName -CollectionName $CollectionName -MasterKey $MasterKey
```

**Cosmos creation script**

```
$resourceGroupName='mytestcosmos'
$accountName='testcosmosaccount' 
az group create -l westus -n $resourceGroupName
az cosmosdb create --name $accountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName 


$databaseName='database1'

az cosmosdb database create -n $accountName -g $resourceGroupName -d $databaseName --throughput 1000

$collectionName = 'collection1'
$partitionKey = '/name'

az cosmosdb collection create -g $resourceGroupName -n $accountName -d $databaseName -c $collectionName --partition-key-path $partitionKey
```

Comment: There should be more to the response than (400) Bad Request. It should have more info. Usually the problem is with the signature. Does `Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature` work correctly when you use it for other things?

Comment: One interesting the above code does work for older collections when while creating it was created with the default partition key(about a year back) but it does not work for newer collections where we have to put the partition key when creating collection

Comment: @kumar Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to call Azure Cosmos DB rest api with PowerShell, please refer to the following script

```
$Key="<your master key>"
$Verb="POST"
$ResourceType="docs"
$ResourceLink ="dbs/ToDoList/colls/Items"
$Date= (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
$KeyType="master"
$TokenVersion="1.0"

# create Authorization header
$StringToSign=$Verb.ToLowerInvariant()+"`n" +$ResourceType.ToLowerInvariant() +"`n" +$ResourceLink + "`n" +$Date.ToLowerInvariant() + "`n" + "" + "`n";
$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Key)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($StringToSign))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$authorization = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=${KeyType}&ver=${TokenVersion}&sig=$signature")

#call rest api
$query=@"
{  
  "query": "SELECT * FROM c",  
  "parameters": [  ]  
} 
"@

$header = @{Authorization=$authorization;"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-documentdb-isquery"="True";"x-ms-date"=$Date}
$contentType= "application/query+json"
$CosmosDBEndPoint="https://stancosmosdb.documents.azure.com/"
$url=$CosmosDBEndPoint+$ResourceLink+"/docs"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType -Uri $url -Headers $header -Body $query
```

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents

Comment: I tried above code but with the same result "(400) Bad Request". I have added script to create cosmos above. You should be able to reproduce the error message. Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: @kumar According to my result, Azure CosmosDB rest api uses Gateway Connectivity Mode to connect Azure CosmosDB. But when we use Gateway Connectivity Mode, it does not support Aggregates function (such as count()). For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#queries-that-cannot-be-served-by-gateway and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/restful-interactions-with-cosmosdb-resources#connectivity-options

Comment: Can i ask why you need use PowerShell to query Cosmos?

Comment: The code is not working. Any update on this code. Still error ' 400 Bad request"

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS You can try to use fiddler to catch your request to get detailed error message

Answer (score 0):

@Jim XU Code is almost right. But adding ""x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition" = "True"" in header works pretty well with no issues.

```
  $header = @{Authorization=$authorization;"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-documentdb-isquery"="True";"x-ms-date"=$Date;"x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition" = "True"}
```